# How to allow hyphens in this regex?

Tags: regex

I have this regex I'm using for username validation, but I don't understand regex very well.

Anyone can help me change this to allow hyphens please?

```
/^(?!.*[_.]$)(?=.{8,30}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+$/
```

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9._]` => `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]`

Comment: Hyphens in Classes `[chars]` are a special character that is called a `range operator` like `A-Z` all chars from A to Z. To match a hyphen literal when it's not a range, just escape it like `[A-Z\-0-9]`